# GCC: Cross compilation on Angstrom (BeagleBone Black)

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack, angstrom-linux

I am running Angstrom ( v2012.12) on my BeagleBone Black (Linux beaglebone 3.8.13 #1 SMP Thu Sep 12 10:27:06 CEST 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux). I am using the following gcc:

```
COLLECT_GCC=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3/lto-wrapper

...

gcc version 4.7.3 20130205
```

I needed to install some library on BBB and while running the script I got this error: `"gcc: error: unrecognized command line option -m32"`. After googling around I figured out that I need a cross compilation to be able to do that (I hope that is the right way, perhaps I am doing something wrong). I started looking for the appropriate toolchain: `angstrom-eglibc-i686-armv7a-vfp-neon-v2012.12-toolchain.gz`, but I did not find too much. Since http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/toolchains is still out of order I only found a few place where I could get the archive, but it was corrupted.

So my questions are the following.

1. Am I correct with all this cross compilation stuff, would it help we to solve my problem?
2. If I am on the right track can somebody share a toolchain packet or give a valid link.

I would really appreciate any help. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to that problem. Eventually I adjusted the installation script to omit undesired options ("-m32" in this case) and it worked.